# How to split git diff output into individual files

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to split git diff output into individual files.

Say there are three changed files. `git diff` will output all three diffs once, but is there any way to separate them into three individual diff files instead?

Comment: You could split on the line that says `diff --git a/<filename> b/<filename>`

Comment: Or it could be better to find out which files were modified then `git diff` each of them individually.

Comment: Any command that will allow me to do split that way, @wjandrea. git diff each of them individually can work for three changed files, but that's just an example. what if there are dozens of files. I am look for an automatic way, not manual way

Comment: I'm not aware of a single command that can do that, but you could write a script.

Comment: ok, I was hoping for some existing feature, like splitting different commits into their own individual files... alright then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bare bone example bash script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
git diff --name-only | while read p
do
    git diff -- "$p"
    # do something...
done
```

Comment: This is a case where you really should put a `--` before the path (as in `git diff -- "$p"`), because in a scripted context you'd have no idea what filenames you might stumble across that could make the command ambiguous.